# Does Pink Floyd really start a supremacist/hate rally in The Wall?

Tags: meaning, pink-floyd

In the song, *In The Flesh Part II* from Pink Floyd's album, *The Wall*,  the main character, the rock star Pink Floyd, takes the stage and performs a Hitler-esque hate-speech rally. This continues with a campaign of supremacy and depicts a faction obviously supposed to mimic the Nazis. This all continues up to *Waiting For The Worms*

My question is, is he trying to convince his fans to join this "Hammer" campaign, or are the events all just in his head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pink does not start a Neo Nazi rally.  "Pink isn't well, he stayed back at the hotel", to borrow a line from In The Flesh Part II.  In fact, Pink is in a drug-induced stupor in a hotel room and is watching a British movie called [*The Dam Busters* (1955)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dam_Busters_(film)), which centers around World War II, when he begins to hallucinate about the rally.

Obviously, there's a tie-in to Roger Waters' father's death in WWII and his well documented hatred for playing the huge stadiums they played on the Animals tour, which culminated in Waters actually spitting on a fan in anger at the tour finale in Montreal, Gilmour walking off stage before the encore because he was so disgusted with Waters, and Waters' concept of building a wall between the band and the audience (which they literally did on the tour for The Wall in 1980).